# How to pass children class then parent class is required in constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a state machine with Dart,
I am stuck now, I usually did everything in C++, and I would just pass a pointer for a task like this, but in Dart, I am not sure how to do this.
Basically I have created:

```
class state
{
  some methods
}

class MenuState extends State
{
  overridden methods
}
```

now I need that my state machine class would take all children of the state as a correct argument,
So basically what I have written.

```
class StateMachine
{
  StateMachine(State newState)
}

void main()
{
  MenuState myMenuState  = new MenuSatate();

  StateMachine stateM = new StateMachine(myMenuState);
}
```

I get the error that I cannot pass the myMenuState even it is a child of State. How do I work this around in dart?

Comment: Is the code that you posted exactly what you have in your code? There are some obvious errors that may not be actually in your real code.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this error.

Answer (score 0):

The code  looks like this

main.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flame/util.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flame/flame.dart';
import 'stateMachine/gameLoop.dart';


void main() async
{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Util flameUtil = Util();
  await flameUtil.fullScreen();
  await flameUtil.setOrientation(DeviceOrientation.portraitUp);
  MyGame game = new MyGame();
  runApp(game.widget);


}
```

state.dart

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyState extends StatefulWidget
{

   @override
  MyState()
  {
      initialiaze();
  }

  void initialiaze() async
  {


  }

  void render(Canvas canvas) 
  {



  }

  void update(double t) 
  {

  }

  void resize(Size size) 
  {

  }


  void onTapDown(TapDownDetails d)
  {

  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

menuState.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../stateMAchine/state.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

class MenuState extends State<MyState>
{
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }


 @override
  void initialiaze() async
  {
    print("menu State initliazed");
  }
 @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) 
  {



  }
 @override
  void update(double t) 
  {

  }
 @override
  void resize(Size size) 
  {

  }

 @override
  void onTapDown(TapDownDetails d)
  {

  }

}
```

stateMachine.dart

```
import "state.dart";



MyState stateReference;

class StateMachine
{
  StateMachine(MyState ref)
  {
    initialiaze(ref);
  }

 void initialiaze(MyState ref) async
  {
    ref.initialiaze();

  }

}
```

gameLoop.dart
this is there error comes, then I start to put menuState as an argument

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flame/flame.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'stateMachine.dart';
import '../states/menuState.dart';
import 'state.dart';


class MyGame extends Game {
  Size screenSize;
  double tileSize;
  MenuState menuState;
  StateMachine stateMachine;
  Random rnd;

  MyGame()
  {
    initialiaze();
  }

  void initialiaze() async
  {
    resize(await Flame.util.initialDimensions());
    rnd = Random();
    menuState = new MenuState();
    stateMachine = new StateMachine(menuState);
  }


  void render(Canvas canvas) 
  {
    Rect bgRect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    Paint bgPaint = Paint();
    bgPaint.color = Color(0xff576574);
    canvas.drawRect(bgRect, bgPaint); 


  }

  void update(double t) 
  {

  }

  void resize(Size size) 
  {

  }


  void onTapDown(TapDownDetails d)
  {

  }
}
```